# Running Node.js Application with html server

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

i currently learn Node.js development and i try to start my Webcode. Im working with Visual Studio Code on Windows.

When i start the application with "npm start", the website on "localhost:3000/" just shows the "Server Connect". But how do i see all of the other files like the "Index.html"? Do i have to add them anywhere?

Thank you in advance.

```js
Https Server File:

const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.write('Server connect');
    res.end();
}).listen('3000');
```

```js
package.json

{
  "name": "project-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project 1",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are accessing http://localhost:3000? Just append `index.html` to the end like: `http://localhost:3000/index.html`

Comment: @berkobienb — That won't make any difference. The code in the question doesn't pay any addition to the path component of the URL in the request.

Comment: @Quentin good call.

Answer (score 1):

Write code which looks at `req`. A property on that object there will tell you the path that is being asked for. (The API documentation for the `http` module will tell you what property that is).

Then decide what you want to respond with based on that path.

If it is a static file, then read that static file from the file system and output it in the response.

Make sure you set the right `Content-Type` headers. (You'll get problems if you send HTML but say it is plain text or a JPEG image which you say is HTML).

---

You are reinventing the wheel here. You should probably look at the Express.js framework and its `static` module.

Answer (score 0):

To add what @Quentin said. Here's a good example from W3.

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs.asp?filename=demo_ref_http

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```